# The batch file user input using Echo is not the same as manual entry

Tags: batch-file, input, cmd, echo

I am creating the batch to automate the initial setup. I noticed that batch file input is not the same as user input.  When I use batch file input for PIN and then I try to enter it manually it does not match. I have tried the input with space like [space]1111 but it was also not the valid PIN. I know there is a way to set user input from another file, but I wanted to have it all in one batch file.

```
(Echo 1111&Echo 1111&Echo 1111&Echo 1111)|ctconf
```

Command line output:

> C:\windows\system32>(Echo 1111&Echo 1111&Echo 1111&Echo 1111)|ctconf
>
> Initializing Admin Token SO and Administrator PINs (Device 0, S/N:
>   0000): Please enter new Admin SO pin: Please confirm new Admin SO pin:
>
> Please enter new Administrator's pin: Please confirm new
>   Administrator's pin:
>
> The echo command should set PIN to 1111 . When I go and log in
>   manually it is not the correct PIN. I assume that echo is adding the
>   space or alter the input PIN.
>
> C:\windows\system32>ctkmu l -s1
>
> Do you wish to view private (user) objects [y/N]: y
>
> Please enter User's PIN for the token in slot 1:
>
> Label             = AdminToken (0000) Flags             = 0x1001064d
>   (RNG LOGIN-REQ USER-PIN-INIT CLOCK TOKEN-INIT DUAL-CRYPTO USER-LOW)
>
> Could not log user in (0xa0 - PIN incorrect)
>
> ctkmu: List operation failed 0xa0 - PIN incorrect
>
> C:\windows\system32>

IF I start process over and enter PIN 1111 manually then it works:

Command line output:

> C:\windows\system32>ctconf
>
> Initializing Admin Token SO and Administrator PINs (Device 0, S/N:
>   0000): Please enter new Admin SO pin: Please confirm new Admin SO pin:
>
> Please enter new Administrator's pin: Please confirm new
>   Administrator's pin:
>
> C:\windows\system32>ctkmu l -s1
>
> Do you wish to view private (user) objects [y/N]: y
>
> Please enter User's PIN for the token in slot 1:
>
> Label             = AdminToken (0000) Flags             = 0x1000064d
>   (RNG LOGIN-REQ USER-PIN-INIT CLOCK TOKEN-INIT DUAL-CRYPTO)
>
> Public and Private Objects: Slot 0                           - SLOT
>   HIMK                             - SECRET_KEY      DES3 Adapter Config
>   - ADAPTER FwUpgradeCert                    - CERTIFICATE     RSA          (trusted)
>
> C:\windows\system32>

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Reading stdin from a pipe `|` is different behavior to reading from a file `<` as you have noticed.

I do not have `ctconf` to test with, though I know Python 3 has similar behavior with piping. So, I will show some examples with Python which may work with `ctconf`.

Batch file:

```
@prompt $G$S

rem 1. No escaping.
(echo 1111&echo 1111&echo 1111&echo 1111) | py test1.py

rem 2. Escape ampersand and end with a dummy command.
(echo 1111^&echo 1111^&echo 1111^&echo 1111^&echo:>nul) | py test1.py

rem 3. Escape ampersand, newline and end with a dummy command.
(   echo 1111^&^
    echo 1111^&^
    echo 1111^&^
    echo 1111^&^
    echo:>nul
) | py test1.py

pause
```

Python file test1.py:

```
# Use these inputs to catch the stdin.
in1 = input('input1: ')
in2 = input('input2: ')
in3 = input('input3: ')
in4 = input('input4: ')

# Add a newline as inputs display no newlines.
print('\n---')

# Repr is representation so the space can be seen.
print(repr(in1), repr(in2), repr(in3), repr(in4))
```

Run the Batch file and output is:

> ```
> > rem 1. No escaping.
>
> > (echo 1111  & echo 1111  & echo 1111  & echo 1111 )  | py test1.py
> input1: input2: input3: input4:
> ---
> '1111 ' '1111 ' '1111 ' '1111 '
>
> > rem 2. Escape ampersand and end with a dummy command.
>
> > (echo 1111&echo 1111&echo 1111&echo 1111&echo: 1>nul )  | py test1.py
> input1: input2: input3: input4:
> ---
> '1111' '1111' '1111' '1111'
>
> > rem 3. Escape ampersand, newline and end with a dummy command.
>
> > (echo 1111&    echo 1111&    echo 1111&    echo 1111&    echo: 1>nul )  | py test1.py
> input1: input2: input3: input4:
> ---
> '1111' '1111' '1111' '1111'
>
> > pause
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Note: The single quotes in the output are just representation of a string value and are not the value itself.

The 1st example has no escaping done, like in OP, and the output has a trailing space i.e. `'1111 '`.

The 2nd example escapes ampersands and uses a dummy command to allow the last escaped ampersand to exist, else you get a trailing space with the last output value.

The 3rd example is like the 2nd example, though escapes the newline, so the values can be positioned line by line for easier viewing.

The Python file is just an example for displaying the output, so focus on the Batch file code on how to eliminate passing trailing space with use of a pipe `|`.

This is how I solve the trailing spaces with piping and perhaps other, even better solutions may exist.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael. This part worked: rem 3. Escape ampersand, newline and end with a dummy command.
(   echo 1111^&^
    echo 1111^&^
    echo 1111^&^
    echo 1111^&^
    echo:>nul
) | py test1.py